# git rebase issue after rebasing from local master to feature branch and trying to commit to feature branch again

Tags: git

Here is the setup. I have a master branch and two feature branches.

- feature/er
- feature/jm

**Setps:**

- Someone else did changes on feature/jm and merged them with master.
- I committed my changes on feature/er
- checkout master
- git pull
- git checkout feature/er
- git rebase master
- fix conflicts and add
- git rebase --continue
- git status

This is where I now see message :

> On branch feature/er Your branch and 'origin/feature/er' have
>   diverged, and have 5 and 3 different commits each, respectively.
>   (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

Why would this be happening and where did a go wrong ?

Whats the best way around this ?

I thought if I rebased off the local master which has the latest, and fix conflicts then I could just push all the latest to feature/er without any issues ? And my changes would be at the top of all the other changes history because of rebase.

Comment: when you *rebase* you create **new commits** in your feature branch. Therefore your local feature branch "deverged" from the last version you pushed. you have to do `git push -f` (or the safer version `git push --force-with-lease`  to sync

Comment: But wouldn't the same happen if I merged instead of rebase. Either way I'm getting new files from master and trying to push them to my feature/er

Comment: no. *git* does not work with "files", git works with *changes*. So if you merge you (may) create a new commit having the existing (and pushed) commits from *master* **and** your branch as parents. When you *rebase* the new commits in your branch having only "master" as parent. The original commits from your branch become "orphaned".

Comment: Sorry Timothy you completely lost me with your last comment ?

Comment: then you might want to lean [git Basics](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Git-Basics) before continuing...

Comment: Yep that’s what I’m trying to do with the help of stackoverflow.